# Calculating 30d exponential moving average

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics

I have a table of IDs and prices. I want to calculate the 30 and 60 day exponential moving average for each ID.

table looks like the below (dates go from 2022 to 2023)

| Date | ID | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | Goog | 24 |
| 2022-01-01 | META | 46 |
| 2022-01-02 | Goog | 28 |
| 2022-01-02 | META | 42 |
| 2022-01-03 | Goog | 27 |
| 2022-01-03 | META | 42 |

`df.groupby(['date','ID'])['price'].apply(lambda x: x.ewm(span=30, adjust=False).mean())`

Comment: Don't group by 'Date' and 'ID' but only by 'ID'.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['EWM'] = (df.sort_values('Date').groupby('ID')['Price']
               .ewm(span=30, adjust=False).mean().droplevel('ID'))
print(df)

# Output
         Date    ID  Price        EWM
0  2022-01-01  Goog     24  24.000000
1  2022-01-01  META     46  46.000000
2  2022-01-02  Goog     28  24.258065
3  2022-01-02  META     42  45.741935
4  2022-01-03  Goog     27  24.434964
5  2022-01-03  META     42  45.500520
```

Comment: I get the error - 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'ewm'

Comment: 1.1.5. Do i need to set the date as index?

Comment: No it's not necessary, you have just to update your version of Pandas

Comment: Can't update my version of pandas. On a specific version for a reason. You know how I could make it work with this version

Comment: Updated pandas to 1.3.5 still same error

Comment: @NFTcentral. It works for me with Pandas=1.3.5! Can you try `df.sort_values('Date').groupby('ID')['Price'].apply(lambda x: x.ewm(span=30, adjust=False).mean())`?

Comment: I get an output for the above but it doesn't have the date in there so its difficult to join back to original dataframe

Comment: Does it produce another error: `df.sort_values('Date').groupby('ID')[['Price']].apply(lambda x: x.ewm(span=30, adjust=False).mean())`

Comment: The above also gets me an output but again there's no dates

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have no date, just use `df['EWM'] = df.sort_values('Date').groupby('ID')[['Price']].apply(lambda x: x.ewm(span=30, adjust=False).mean()).squeeze()`

Comment: The above gets me the error - incompatible index of inserted column with frame index

Comment: Did you solve your problem or you are still stuck?